# In the given code can someone please explain me this code snippet for (int i=0; i<len; i++) count[str[i]]++;

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ASCII_SIZE 256

using namespace std;

char getMaxOccuringChar(char* str)
{ 
    int count[ASCII_SIZE] = {0};

    // Construct character count array from the input
    // string.
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        count[str[i]]++;
   // can someone please explain me this for loop

    int max = -1;  // Initialize max count
    char result;   // Initialize result

    // Traversing through the string and maintaining
    // the count of each character
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (max < count[str[i]]) {
            max = count[str[i]];
            result = str[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and watch the values of the `count[]` array as you single step through the characters in the string. While doing so, maybe ponder the senselessness of this function's use of *two* loops, when one will suffice for everything it is trying to accomplish.

Comment: int len = strlen(str); - total characters in string. Loop over the string and for each unique character set a counter in count. For each instance of the character, increment its counter.

Comment: This program exhibits UB. What if chars are signed?

Answer (score 0):

> // can someone please explain me this for loop

Simplify the code a bit and add a line of code to produce some useful output.

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    // Simplify this line
    // count[str[i]]++;

    int index = str[i];
    count[index]++;

    // Add helpful output to understand the code.
    std::cout << "Changed the value of count[" << index << "] to " << count[index] << std::endl;
}
```

The output should throw some light on what's happening there.